# Ocultar botón en formulario con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Un placer saludarlos de nuevo, verán tengo una duda, estoy haciendo un formulario con HTML CSS y JavaScript, este formulario al tener muchas preguntas decidí mostrarlas en secciones, al presionar el botón de siguiente o anterior se ocultan estas secciones.

```js
// Página actual
let curPage = 0;
// Obtener páginas y botones
let pages = document.querySelectorAll('.form-page');
let btnPrev = document.querySelector('#btn-prev');
let btnNext = document.querySelector('#btn-next');

// Función para avanzar o retroceder, recibe 1 (avanzar) o -1 (retroceder)
function showPage(action) {
    // Página a mostrar según el valor recibido
    curPage += action;
    // Validar que la página a mostrar esté dentro de los límites
    if(curPage < 0) {
        curPage = 0;
    }
    if(curPage >= pages.length) {
        curPage = pages.length - 1;
    }
    // Recorrer para mostrar u ocultar
    pages.forEach((page, index) => {
        if(index == curPage) {
            // Es página actual, se debe mostrar
            page.classList.add('active');
        } else {
            // Las demás se van a ocultar
            page.classList.remove('active');
        }
    });
    // Habilitar o deshabilitar botones
    btnPrev.disabled = (curPage == 0);
    btnNext.disabled = (curPage == pages.length - 1);
};
// Asignar evento a botones para avanzar y retroceder
btnPrev.addEventListener('click', e => showPage(-1));
btnNext.addEventListener('click', e => showPage(1));
```

```css
.form-page {
    display: none;
}
.form-page.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-page active">
    <h2>Página 1</h2>
    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">
</div>

<div class="form-page">
    <h2>Página 2</h2>
    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">
</div>

<div class="form-buttons">
    <button type="button" id="btn-prev" disabled>Anterior</button>
    <button type="button" id="btn-next">Siguiente</button>
</div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Con este código puedo moverme entre secciones pero no puedo lograr que se oculten los botones si les doy estilos a cada uno, lo que necesito hacer es cuando se está en el inicio del formulario se oculte el botón de "Anterior" y cuando se esté en el final del formulario se oculte el botón de "Siguiente". Si quito el css que le he dado a ambos botones se puede apreciar el efecto del cambio del botón a disabled pero necesito darle css a esos botones, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el CSS, solo así podemos comprobar el comportamiento para ver si entendemos lo que quieres hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Podrías utilizar `style.display` para ocultar o mostrar los botones

Si quieres hacerlo en una línea puedes utilizar el [operador ternario](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
btnPrev.style.display = (curPage == 0) ? 'none' : 'inline-block';
btnNext.style.display = (curPage == pages.length - 1) ? 'none' : 'inline-block';
```

Otra opción es hacer un `if`

Te dejo el ejemplo completo:

```js
// Página actual
let curPage = 0;
// Obtener páginas y botones
let pages = document.querySelectorAll('.form-page');
let btnPrev = document.querySelector('#btn-prev');
let btnNext = document.querySelector('#btn-next');

// Función para avanzar o retroceder, recibe 1 (avanzar) o -1 (retroceder)
function showPage(action) {
    // Página a mostrar según el valor recibido
    curPage += action;
    // Validar que la página a mostrar esté dentro de los límites
    if(curPage < 0) {
        curPage = 0;
    }
    if(curPage >= pages.length) {
        curPage = pages.length - 1;
    }
    // Recorrer para mostrar u ocultar
    pages.forEach((page, index) => {
        if(index == curPage) {
            // Es página actual, se debe mostrar
            page.classList.add('active');
        } else {
            // Las demás se van a ocultar
            page.classList.remove('active');
        }
    });
    // Habilitar o deshabilitar botones
    btnPrev.disabled = (curPage == 0);
    btnNext.disabled = (curPage == pages.length - 1);
        btnPrev.style.display = (curPage == 0) ? 'none' : 'inline-block';
    btnNext.style.display = (curPage == pages.length - 1) ? 'none' : 'inline-block';
    
};
// Asignar evento a botones para avanzar y retroceder
btnPrev.addEventListener('click', e => showPage(-1));
btnNext.addEventListener('click', e => showPage(1));
```

```html
<div class="form-page active">
    <h2>Página 1</h2>
    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">
</div>

<div class="form-page">
    <h2>Página 2</h2>
    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

    <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">
</div>

<div class="form-buttons">
    <button type="button" id="btn-prev" disabled>Anterior</button>
    <button type="button" id="btn-next">Siguiente</button>
</div>
```